How to authenticate when using an Azure Function from a Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App?
I have a Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App that is configured to use authentication. This seems to work. I also have an Azure Function that requires authentication. When I log in to https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad, everything works through the browser. However, I'm unsure how to perform authentication for the Azure Functions app through the Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App. I always get a 401.
I've tried posting the access token from the Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App to https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad, but I get a 401. I've also tried including the access token in the Authorization header, as a Bearer token, when performing a get to the Azure Function, but I also get a 401.
This is a common scenario, no? Perhaps my Google and Copilot skills just aren't up to snuff?
As per the request of Harshitha, here is my project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Please share your .csproj file.

@Harshitha, I added my .csproj file.

Checking from my end.Can you please share the screenshot of your folder structure ?Is function app and blazor or in same folder/directory ?
